# skimage hough circle detection -- particles edges detected but circles not drawn

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, scikit-image, hough-transform

I am trying to use skimage to detect virus particles in microscopy images. I notice it looks like edge detection is fairly accurate, but I still miss some particles. I looked at other questions related to this problem, but they didn't seem relevant.

Here is an example:

```py
def return_edges_circles(im, hough_radii, min_xdistance=1, min_ydistance=1):
    edges = canny(im, sigma=4, low_threshold=1, high_threshold=5)
    
    hough_res = hough_circle(edges, hough_radii)
    accums, cx, cy, radii = hough_circle_peaks(hough_res, hough_radii, min_xdistance=min_xdistance, min_ydistance=min_ydistance, total_num_peaks=100)

    image = color.gray2rgb(im)
    
    for center_y, center_x, radius in zip(cy, cx, radii):
        circy, circx = circle_perimeter(center_y, center_x, radius, shape=image.shape)
        image[circy, circx] = (220, 20, 20)
        
    return edges, image, [cy, cx, radii]
```

[image: left: original image; mid: edges; right: detected circles]

I rarely expect to see more than 100 viruses per image, so I set `max_num_peaks` (defined in the skimage documentation [here](https://www.kite.com/python/docs/skimage.transform.hough_circle_peaks)) to 100, but I get significantly less than 100 circles, which makes me think that 1 peak != 1 circle? I want something robust, upping the peaks here to 150 results in more circled particles, but going higher leads to false positives.

I have very little experience with computer vision / image processing, so in addition to my main question, which is:

- Why am I missing some particles if the edges are nicely drawn? What parameters, besides `max_num_peaks`, can / should I play with?

I also would like general advice, if relevant, for the following:

- I want this to be as automated as possible, generally we have some idea of the radius, so passing a range of radii to the hough circle function is not an issue, but how can I account for differences in contrast/background noise between images?

using python 3.8.x and skimage 0.18.3

Comment: One peak equals one circle. However, you set the minimum distances between circle centers very small (only 1 px in both dimensions), and as your image resolution is probably pretty large, several viral particles with multiple peaks at their center are assigned multiple circles that are near identical and appear as one circle. For example, you can see in the upper right hand corner a particle that seems to have a much stronger red "halo" than neighbouring particles. `circle_perimeter` draws circles with one pixel wide lines so that is a pretty clear indication of the problem.

Comment: Regarding your contrast issues, I have had good results with [local histogram equalisation](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/auto_examples/color_exposure/plot_local_equalize.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-color-exposure-plot-local-equalize-py) when applied to EM images. However, if the viral prep is dirty and there are some very dark particles left then this can also backfire if your viral particles have a much lower contrast in comparison.